# Game Center Turn Based matches. Multiple type match inside one game?

Tags: objective-c, game-center, gkturnbasedmatch

Im extending my game with Game Center turn based matches. However my game got 4 game mode and I woud like to make a Multiplayer mode for all. I have successfully made the first mode however if I try to load an another GKTurnBasedMatchMakerViewController I get the same matches and same game as in the first mode. Is there any way to make different type of matches inside one game?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible with the [playerGroup](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GameKit/Reference/GKMatchRequest_Ref/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/GKMatchRequest/playerGroup) property of a `GKMatchRequest`. When you assign it to the request it will create a match only if it can find another player with a match request of the same group. Read [GKMatchRequest Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GameKit/Reference/GKMatchRequest_Ref/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/GKMatchRequest) for more information.

Comment: Thanks, it helped a lot :). However I have another question: Is it possible to list the active games depends on the playGroup? Or just display the game modes seperated.